# cant access object inside an array React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const data = [];
// Note: the empty deps array [] means
// this useEffect will run once
// similar to componentDidMount()
const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
const user = jwtDecode(jwt)

const token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/animals/animal/client?clientId=" + user.id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token}`,
        },
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {


                var mydata = (result[0].peso)

                data.push(mydata)



                var isArray = Array.isArray(data);

                console.log(data)

            },

            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            }
        )


}, [])
```

when i do a console.log of an element inside an array it says undefined but when i do only the console.log of the array it gives me data like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTkK1.png)

PS im using this to use in a chart but before that i need to access the elements

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Is `data` array? If so, it shouldn't has `data` prop (`data.data`). If not, you can't call `push`. And where you declare `data` anyway?

Comment: Where does `data` come from? Why are you not setting state (data) when there's no error?

Comment: i edited the post with all info

Answer (score 1):

> when i do a console.log of an element inside an array it says undefined

You aren't doing that. `data` is the array therefore `data.data` is a property named `data` *on the array* and not of an object inside it.

You have to read the `data` property *of the object* (or at least one of the 5 objects you have inside the array) not *of the array*.

```
console.log(data[someIndex].data)
```

Comment: i did console.log(data[1]) and still says undefined

Comment: @User007 — Your edit shows that where you were logging `data.data` you are now just logging `data` and you don't log `data[1].data` anywhere.

Comment: yes but i tried with that too says undefined

Comment: @User007 — Going back and rereading your code, I can't see any way for you to get the result the screenshot shows. You create the array at the top of your component, you then have a useEffect which gets called once (because the dependency array is empty), and inside it you call `data.push` once … so you can't have more than 1 item in it, ever. That tracks with `data[1]` being undefined and means the screenshot showing it with 5 items in it doesn't make sense. You need to provide an [mcve] of your problem combined with a description of the results that the version of the code you show us gives.

Comment: id did console.log(data) to show what is in the screenshot it says undefined when i try to get inside of that